# How to turn this command into a zsh function

Tags: zsh

This is the command I want to translate into a zsh function, which does a global search and replace for a string:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/' {} \;
```

I tried:

```
gr () {
    find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/$1/$2/' {} \;
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: not very helpful without the output you are getting.  How do you know it is not working?  Have you run the zsh function with debug set?  What is the output when invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious error is the wrong quoting -- as always. `'` prevents the shell to expand the variables, which is what you want. Use `"` instead -- and probably you also want the *global* flag for sed:

```
gr () {
    find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/$1/$2/g" {} \;
}
```

However, this is not very `zsh`-stylish... the following is shorter and IMHO better to read:

```
gr () {
    sed -i "s/$1/$2/g" **/*(.)
}
```

- `**` searches recursively, but does not follow symlinks (use `***` if you want that)
- `(.)` limits the results to plain files

Comment: Be careful if either the before or after text contains a `/`; make sure to escape them. For example, `gr "meters per second" "m\/s"`

Comment: Or use `sed -i "s#${1//#/\\#}#${2//#/\\#}#g" **/*(.)`. It's ugly, but will ensure that any characters in the two arguments that match the `sed` delimiter will be properly escaped.